# How can I use lambda in vector of type int?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> graphPred(tot_lines);
```

that I set to various values but when the input is done I would like to eliminate empty cells I tried:

```
graphPred.erase(std::remove_if(graphPred.begin(), graphPred.end(),
                [](const int graphPred){return graphPred.empty();}),
            graphPred.end());
```

but the compiler is complaining that "expression must be a class type"
Is there a problem with my syntax or another way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You're calling `empty()` with an object of type `int`.

Comment: Are empty cells equal to 0 or something?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes they are 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"yes they are 0"*

So use this:

```
  graphPred.erase(std::remove_if(graphPred.begin(), graphPred.end(),
                    [](const int x){return x==0;}),
                graphPred.end());
```

Your lambda function

`[](const int graphPred){return graphPred.empty();}`

is using `empty` on an `int`, which is wrong, member functions are called on class, and that's what the error all about

Comment: @Napalidon `std::remove` will do the job too. With less typing even ;)

Comment: @catscradle But I heard that std::remove doesn't really remove elements and that why using remove_if lambda is better, is that true?

Comment: @Napalidon No, they work exactly the same. Even in this answer you can see that you have to use `std::erase` to actually delete those elements.

Comment: @catscradle Scott Meyers's **Item 32 & 33**

Comment: @P0W What about those items? You didn't liked my use of word "delete" or something?

Comment: You don't need the lambda, just do `...(remove(graphPred.begin(), graphPred.end(), 0), ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote does not make sense: `const int graphPred` "shadows" the `graphPred` outside (which wouldn't be captured anyway, because the square brackets are empty). It is calling `empty` on an `int` that triggers the error that you see.

Moreover, if `graphPred` is `empty()`, there is nothing to erase from it, so you need some sort of a meaningful logic expression in your lambda.

This should work - it will erase all even numbers from the vector:

```
graphPred.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        graphPred.begin()
    ,   graphPred.end()
    ,   [](const int n){return n % 2 == 0;}
    )
,   graphPred.end()
);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Bv4HmY).

Comment: Thanks, now I see how to use lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You declear the lambda as:

```
[](const int graphPred){return graphPred.empty();}
```

So `graphPred`is a const int not a class. You can not cal `graphPred.empty()`